# add the class of a kendo ui cell /Or/ Allow numbers only in one column

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, nativescript-telerik-ui

Add the class of a kendo ui cell /Or/ Allow numbers only in one column

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.GroupOfAllowancesKendoGrid)
          .Name("gridAllowance")
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
              .Model(model => model.Field(field => field.EmployeeName).Editable(false))
                      .Model(model => model.Field(field => field.Department).Editable(false))
                      .Model(model => model.Field(field => field.Section).Editable(false))
              .Model(model => model.Field(field => field.AllowanceValue).Editable(true))
              .Batch(true)
              .Read(read => read.Action("GroupAllowances_Read", "Allowanes").Data("additionalInfo"))
          )
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(p => p.EmployeeId).Hidden().Visible(false);
              columns.Bound(c => c.EmployeeName).Width(50);
              columns.Bound(c => c.Department).Width(40);
              columns.Bound(c => c.Section).Width(40);
              columns.Bound(c => c.DepartmentId).Hidden().Visible(false);
              columns.Bound(c => c.SectionId).Hidden().Visible(false);
              columns.Bound(p => p.AllowanceValue).Width(50);
          })
          .Scrollable(x => x.Enabled(true))
          .Sortable(x => x.Enabled(true))
          .Filterable(x => x.Enabled(true).Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
          .Events(e => e.DataBound("onRowBound"))
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    )
```

how can I allow numbers (numeric/double) in `AllowanceValue` column

Comment: Is AllowanceValue an Int or a Double? If so the column should already allow only numbers.